# How to prepare animated after effect files for iOS?

Tags: animation, mobile, iphone

What's the best way to prepare a motion graphic that has been animated in After Effects to be used in iOS/Android (assuming they're similar) ?

A common example of this is an animation in an app's onboarding, like https://dribbble.com/shots/1988895-Onboarding-animation?list=buckets&offset=5.

Comment: I don't really know a single thing about embedding video in ios or android apps, but Edge Animate might be a better option.

Comment: Groups of image sequences would technically do the trick. But you should ask your develop what files he expects.

Comment: http://www.marcuseckert.com/squall is an AfterEffects plugin that exports animations in a format that can then be played by the provided iOS framework. Seems promising